# Unable to create a bucket with awscli, but able to through the website interface

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, bucket

When I try the single command: `aws s3api create-bucket --bucket dskljfslkdjflksjdf2342` I get the error message:

`An error occurred (SlowDown) when calling the CreateBucket operation (reached max retries: 4): Please reduce your request rate.`

But I am able to create a bucket through the AWS website.

I have no idea why this is happening. I have been creating and deleting buckets all day (less than a hundred in the last 24 hours). And I have only 3 buckets right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're trying that in the `us-east-1` AWS region, it's probably because AWS currently has severe problems with S3 there. From their [status page](http://status.aws.amazon.com/):

> Amazon Simple Storage Service (N. Virginia)
>
> Increased Error Rates
>
> 11:58 AM PDT We are investigating increased error rates for Amazon S3 requests in the US-EAST-1 Region.
>
> 12:21 PM PDT We can confirm that some customers are receiving throttling errors accessing S3. We are currently investigating the root cause.
>
> 12:38 PM PDT We continue to work towards resolving the increased throttling errors for Amazon S3 requests in the US-EAST-1 Region. We have identified the subsystem responsible for the errors, identified root cause and are now working to resolve the issue.